# SysCallError(10054) and SysCallError(-1) watson NLU Errors when passing multiple rquest

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-nlu

When I **passed multiple request** to the **IBM Watson natural language understanding** API then I got two errors

**First one is :-**
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /natural-language-understanding/api/v1/analyze?version=2018-03-16 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(10054'"

**Second one is :-**
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /natural-language-understanding/api/v1/analyze?version=2018-03-16 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1'"

**Code snippet:-**

```
        natural_language_understanding = NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1(
            url=self.set_object.watson_nlu_url,
            version='2018-03-16',
            username=self.set_object.watson_nlu_username,
            password=self.set_object.watson_nlu_password)

        # Calling the Watson Natural language understanding API
        natural_language_understanding.disable_SSL_verification()
        try:
            response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
                text=str(user_answer_sent),
                features=Features(
                    semantic_roles=SemanticRolesOptions(),
                    sentiment=SentimentOptions()
                ), language='en'
            ).get_result()
```

**python version**

3.6.6

**watson-developer-cloud python sdk version**

2.4.0

**Is there any limit for multiple calls per seconds in NLU lite plan?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are limited to `20` concurrent requests.

Comment: If we moved to premium plan is there any changes to increase the concurrent request limit?

Comment: Look into the usage limits here: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-understanding/usage-limits.html#analyzed-text